# How to add "portable" to the electron builder .exe file name?

Tags: electron-builder

This is my package.json build data:

```
"build": {
    "appId": "name.desktop",
    "productName": "name",
    "beforePack": "electron/beforePack.js",
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "bin/${os}",
        "to": "bin",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "electron/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "extends": null,
    "mac": {
      "target": "dmg",
      "type": "distribution"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "portable", 
        "nsis"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": "AppImage"
    }
  }
```

I'm looking to add "portable" to the windows portable file name, so that the .exe is "name 1.0.0 portable.exe" instead of "name 1.0.0.exe"

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to explicitely define the generated file names at each relevant level in the `package.json` file by making use of an `"artifactName"` property.

This is documented in the [Overridable per Platform Options](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration.html#overridable-per-platform-options) section of the **Common Configuration - electron-builder** page:

> Following options can be set also per platform (top-level keys mac, linux and win) if need.
>
> - artifactName String | “undefined” - The [artifact file name template](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#artifact-file-name-template). Defaults to `${productName}-${version}.${ext}` (some target can have other defaults, see corresponding options).

which indirectly refers to the [File Macros](https://www.electron.build/file-patterns#file-macros) section of the **File Patterns - electron-builder** page.

In your specific case, you'll have to add the following `"artifactName"` property to your `package.json` file at the Windows version level:

```
  "artifactName": "${name} ${version} portable.${ext}",
```

i.e.:

```
"build": {
    "appId": "name.desktop",
    "productName": "name",
    "beforePack": "electron/beforePack.js",
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "bin/${os}",
        "to": "bin",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "electron/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "extends": null,
    "mac": {
      "target": "dmg",
      "type": "distribution"
    },
    "win": {
      "artifactName": "${name} ${version} portable.${ext}",
      "target": [
        "portable", 
        "nsis"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": "AppImage"
    }
  }
```

Comment: won't this add "portable" to both the "portable" and "nsis" target? I don't want it to be added to the "nsis" target.